# Why does this wrong object initialisation with curly braces even compile?

Tags: c#, curly-braces, object-initializers

Whille creating some dummy data for a collection for a WPF/MVVM project, I produced the following wrong code, which compiles fine, but throws an exception at runtime.

There's a nested structure of data objects, which I wrongly instantiate with only the curly braces (looks like writing JavaScript does cause permanent damage to the brain).

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace testapp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var collection = new ObservableCollection<TopLevelDataObject>();
            collection.Add(new TopLevelDataObject{Nested = {Bar = 5}});         // NullReferenceException
        }

        class TopLevelDataObject
        {
            public NestedDataObject Nested { get; set; }
            public string Foo { get; set; }
        }

        class NestedDataObject
        {
            public double Bar { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

**Why does that compile?**

If I create an annonymous type, like `Nested = new {Bar = 5}`, I get the error message during compilation (which thus fails):

```
Cannot implicitly convert type '<anonymous type: int Bar>' to 'testapp.Program.NestedDataObject'
```

Why do I not get such an error when ommitting the `new` operator?

It even gives me a code hint for the property:
[image: click to see the image, for I do not have enough rep to embed it yet]

My guess would be that `{Bar = 5}` is simply a code block, which on its own is a valid thing to have.
But why is it valid to assign a code block to anything (in this case, the `Nested` property)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does that compile?

Because when that code is compiled, it is compiled as just a set of assignment operations. It doesn't all have to be new instances you create.

If you construct a new instance of `Nested` from the constructor, you can assign a value to `Nested.Bar`.

Change `public NestedDataObject Nested { get; set; }` to this to see how it works:

```
public NestedDataObject Nested { get; } = new NestedDataObject();
```

(Note you can never assign a value to `Nested` outside the constructor in the above code!)

Answer (score 2):

> Why does that compile?

Because `var x = new SomeType{Property = value};` is the same as:

```
var x = new SomeType();
x.Property = value;
```

Indeed we can even leave in the `()` to have `var x = new SomeType(){Property = value};` or even `var x = new SomeType(argument){Property = value};` combining passing an argument to the constructor and setting a value.

As such you can see that there is always a constructor called, and if you leave out the parentheses that make that explicit its always the nullary (no-argument) constructor.

Meanwhile a type with no explicit constructor always has a public nullary constructor (the "default constructor").

Hence `new TopLevelDataObject{Nested = {Bar = 5}}` is the same as:

```
var temp = new TopLevelDataObject();
temp.Nested.Bar = 5; // NRE on temp.Nested
```

Because `TopLevelDataObject` could have a constructor that sets `Nestedt then the code you have could work, so it should compile. Of course, because it **doesn't** have such a constructor it doesn't work.

(Note that initialisers don't operate quite the same with anonymous types, in that case it gets rewritten to call a hidden constructor hence allowing the properties to be read-only even though initialisers cannot be used with read-only properties of non-anonymous types. The syntax allows them to look the same and hence be easily understood as similar but the result is not the same).

Comment: How was it possible to post answer 15 minutes ago if question was closed 20 minutes ago?

Comment: @Evk I'm curious about that too.

Comment: @Evk There's a grace period that makes this possible, for more info, check this meta question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252711/8958148